# Yajra Datatable return Invalid JSON response

Tags: json, laravel, laravel-5, datatable, yajra-datatable

I use **Yajra Datatable** in my **Laravel** Project . I created my **DataTable** with it and it works correctly for me. But sometimes it gives me the error that by refreshing the page a few times this error will be fixed! Where is the problem?

***Error***:

```
DataTables warning: table id={id} - Invalid JSON response.
```

this is my datatable config :

```
   let table = $('.data-table').DataTable({
            processing: true,
            serverSide: true,
            "language": {
                "infoFiltered":   "(جستجو شده  از _MAX_  پیام)",
                "lengthMenu":     "نمایش _MENU_ پیام",
                "search": "جستجو",
                "processing":"درحال پردازش",
                "emptyTable":'پیامی یافت نشد',
                "infoEmpty":"نمایش 0 پیام از 0 پیام ",
                "loadingRecords":"درحال بارگزاری ",
                "zeroRecords":"پیامی با این نام یافت نشد",
                "info": "نمایش صفحات _PAGE_ از _PAGES_",
                "paginate": {
                    "first":      "اولین",
                    "last":       "آخرین",
                    "next":       "بعدی",
                    "previous":   "قبلی"
                },
            },
            ajax: "{{ route('messages.index') }}",
            columns: [
                {data: 'DT_RowIndex', name: 'DT_RowIndex'},
                {data: 'title', name: 'title'},
                {data: 'date', name: 'date'},
                {data: 'from', name: 'from'},
                {data: 'action', name: 'action', orderable: false, searchable: false},
            ]
        });
```

this is my Controller : ( Index )

```
  public function index(Request $request)
    {
        if ($request->ajax()) {
            $data=null;
            if(auth()->user()->hasRole('admin'))
                $data=Message::all();
            else{
                $data=Message::where('pid',auth()->user()->pid)->get();
            }
            return Datatables::of($data)
                ->addIndexColumn()
                ->addColumn('action', function($row){
                    $btn='<a href="javascript:void(0)" class="edit btn btn-success btn-sm" id="'.$row->id.'">  مشاهده</a>';
                    return $btn;
                })
                ->addColumn('date', function ($row){
                    return Helpers::shamsi($row->created_at);
                })
                ->addColumn('from', function ($row){
                    return User::where('pid',$row->pid)->first()->name;
                })
                ->rawColumns(['action'])
                ->make(true);
        }
        return view("common.message");
```

this is my config/session.php

```
    <?php

use Illuminate\Support\Str;

return [

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Default Session Driver
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This option controls the default session "driver" that will be used on
    | requests. By default, we will use the lightweight native driver but
    | you may specify any of the other wonderful drivers provided here.
    |
    | Supported: "file", "cookie", "database", "apc",
    |            "memcached", "redis", "dynamodb", "array"
    |
    */

    'driver' => env('SESSION_DRIVER', 'file'),

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Session Lifetime
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Here you may specify the number of minutes that you wish the session
    | to be allowed to remain idle before it expires. If you want them
    | to immediately expire on the browser closing, set that option.
    |
    */

    'lifetime' => env('SESSION_LIFETIME', 120),

    'expire_on_close' => false,

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Session Encryption
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This option allows you to easily specify that all of your session data
    | should be encrypted before it is stored. All encryption will be run
    | automatically by Laravel and you can use the Session like normal.
    |
    */

    'encrypt' => false,

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Session File Location
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | When using the native session driver, we need a location where session
    | files may be stored. A default has been set for you but a different
    | location may be specified. This is only needed for file sessions.
    |
    */

    'files' => storage_path('framework/sessions'),

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Session Database Connection
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | When using the "database" or "redis" session drivers, you may specify a
    | connection that should be used to manage these sessions. This should
    | correspond to a connection in your database configuration options.
    |
    */

    'connection' => env('SESSION_CONNECTION', null),

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Session Database Table
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | When using the "database" session driver, you may specify the table we
    | should use to manage the sessions. Of course, a sensible default is
    | provided for you; however, you are free to change this as needed.
    |
    */

    'table' => 'sessions',

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Session Cache Store
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | When using the "apc", "memcached", or "dynamodb" session drivers you may
    | list a cache store that should be used for these sessions. This value
    | must match with one of the application's configured cache "stores".
    |
    */

    'store' => env('SESSION_STORE', null),

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Session Sweeping Lottery
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Some session drivers must manually sweep their storage location to get
    | rid of old sessions from storage. Here are the chances that it will
    | happen on a given request. By default, the odds are 2 out of 100.
    |
    */

    'lottery' => [2, 100],

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Session Cookie Name
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Here you may change the name of the cookie used to identify a session
    | instance by ID. The name specified here will get used every time a
    | new session cookie is created by the framework for every driver.
    |
    */

    'cookie' => env(
        'SESSION_COOKIE',
        Str::slug(env('APP_NAME', 'laravel'), '_').'_session'
    ),

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Session Cookie Path
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | The session cookie path determines the path for which the cookie will
    | be regarded as available. Typically, this will be the root path of
    | your application but you are free to change this when necessary.
    |
    */

    'path' => '/',

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Session Cookie Domain
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Here you may change the domain of the cookie used to identify a session
    | in your application. This will determine which domains the cookie is
    | available to in your application. A sensible default has been set.
    |
    */

    'domain' => env('SESSION_DOMAIN', null),

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | HTTPS Only Cookies
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | By setting this option to true, session cookies will only be sent back
    | to the server if the browser has a HTTPS connection. This will keep
    | the cookie from being sent to you if it can not be done securely.
    |
    */

    'secure' => env('SESSION_SECURE_COOKIE', false),

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | HTTP Access Only
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Setting this value to true will prevent JavaScript from accessing the
    | value of the cookie and the cookie will only be accessible through
    | the HTTP protocol. You are free to modify this option if needed.
    |
    */

    'http_only' => true,

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Same-Site Cookies
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This option determines how your cookies behave when cross-site requests
    | take place, and can be used to mitigate CSRF attacks. By default, we
    | do not enable this as other CSRF protection services are in place.
    |
    | Supported: "lax", "strict"
    |
    */

    'same_site' => null,

];
```

and this is my .env

```
APP_NAME=Laravel
APP_ENV=local
APP_KEY=base64:Yc2LSandFekxm49EibTpo4bzAXAH6ULnfmiUV8zatGs=
APP_DEBUG=true
APP_URL=http://localhost

LOG_CHANNEL=stack

DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=TaskManager
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=

BROADCAST_DRIVER=log
CACHE_DRIVER=file
QUEUE_CONNECTION=sync
SESSION_DRIVER=file
SESSION_LIFETIME=220

REDIS_HOST=127.0.0.1
REDIS_PASSWORD=null
REDIS_PORT=6379

MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.mailtrap.io
MAIL_PORT=2525
MAIL_USERNAME=null
MAIL_PASSWORD=null
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=null

AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=
AWS_DEFAULT_REGION=us-east-1
AWS_BUCKET=

PUSHER_APP_ID=
PUSHER_APP_KEY=
PUSHER_APP_SECRET=
PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER=mt1

MIX_PUSHER_APP_KEY="${PUSHER_APP_KEY}"
MIX_PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER="${PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER}"
```

Comment: Please add the content of your response from your server when you see the `DataTables warning: table id={id} - Invalid JSON response.` error

Comment: @ChristopheHubert  There is no esponse and reponse tab is empty  Status code is 302

Comment: I assume you are getting redirected to the login page due to timeout in your authentication. Where is the 302 redirecting to?

Comment: @ChristopheHubert i don't know How do I increase  timeout time authentication  ?

Comment: Where is the 302 redirecting to?

Comment: @ChristopheHubert How do I know?  Please help a little more

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/214314/discussion-between-ali-dehqani-and-christophe-hubert).

Comment: @ChristopheHubert redirected to http://localhost:8000/login

Comment: check your `config\session.php` file and you can increase the `'lifetime' => 1000` and set `'expire_on_close' => false`

Comment: @ChristopheHubert  i updated my post and change life time please check again